# When moving files to my NAS, the file move dialog doesn't show progress. Why?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, progress

I have a Synology DS1513+ NAS that has a shared folder exposed (I think it's using CIFS). I'm moving files from a HDD on my local machine to the NAS. For some reason the dialog doesn't show any information about what it's currently doing, or even how much data has been transferred or any kind of ETA, which is frustrating.

I'll note that before moving the files I did get a UAC prompt for permission to cut from the F:\ drive (I have different NTFS ACLs).

Here is a screenshot: "Media" is the name of the share and "F:\DVDs" is my source folder.

[image: screenshot of unhelpful progress dialog]

Why isn't information displayed?

Comment: this transfer is via folder explorer ftp or what?

Comment: It's through Windows Explorer - I selected the files, Ctrl+X, opened the destination, then Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 0):

The screen shot shows

> **Moving** ... from DVDs ...

Is the source is a DVD?  Is the DVD read/write?

Try: `Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V`

Comment: "DVDs" is the name of a folder in the root of drive F: which is a standard hard disk drive.